# Attributes of a pointer are turned to NULL after passing to a function

Tags: c, pointers

I have a structure like this.

```
typedef struct
{
  example_t *attr_1;

  int attr_2;
  ...
} my_struct_t;
```

There is a wrapper for this structure.

```
typedef struct
{
   my_struct_t *my_struct1;
} my_struct_wrapper_t;
```

Memory is created for the wrapper and structure and is working fine.

```
my_struct_wrapper_t *wrapper = create_memory();
set_attribute (my_struct_wrapper_t *wrapper);
```

This creates memory for wrapper->my_struct1 as well as my_struct->attr1;

But the problem is when i pass my_struct1 of wrapper to a function like 
this

```
call_function (wrrapper->my_struct1);
void call_function (my_struct_t *my_struct){
   my_struct->attr1 returns NULL.
}
```

Comment: `set_attribute (my_struct_wrapper_t *wrapper);` - this does not do what you think it does.

Comment: After this function `wrapper->my_struct1->attr1` is not NULL. I have verified. Memory for wrapper1 is created before `set_attribute (my_struct_wrapper_t *wrapper)` function.

Comment: You should post code of `set_attribute`, thats the root of evil in my opinion.

Comment: In these two lines: `my_struct_wrapper_t *wrapper = create_memory();
set_attribute (my_struct_wrapper_t *wrapper);`, the first is a function call, the second is (at best) a function declaration with implicit return type of `int` (otherwise, it's just a syntax error).  Maybe you meant to write `set_attribute(wrapper);`?  You should show an MCVE ([MCVE]) so we can see what you're doing.  Does your code compile without warnings, even when the compiler is set to fussy?

Comment: I got a clue. The problem may lie outside the scope of my question. I  will update my question. Thank you